# Adjacent parabolic subgroups and proportionality to $\alpha^{\vee}$

Tags: algebraic-groups, harmonic-analysis, reductive-groups

Let $P = MN$ be a parabolic subgroup of a $p$-adic reductive group $G$ with split component $A_M$.   There is bijection from the set of parabolic subgroups of $G$ with Levi $M$ and the chambers of $\mathfrak a_M$ with respect to  the hyperplanes $H_{\alpha} = \{ h \in \mathfrak a_M : \alpha \in \Phi(A_M,G) \}$, where $P$ corresponds to the chamber

$$\{ h \in \mathfrak a_M : \langle h,\alpha \rangle > 0 \textrm{ for all } \alpha \in \Phi(A_M,N)\}$$

A parabolic subgroup $P' = MN'$ is said to be adjacent to $P$ if the chambers of $P$ and $P'$ are separated by a single hyperplane $H_{\alpha}$.  Then there is a unique simple root $\alpha$ of $A_M$ in $N$ for which $-\alpha$ is a simple root of $A_M$ in $N'$.

Let $K$ be a maximal compact open subgroup of $G$ in good position relative to $P$ and $P'$, so that the Harish-Chandra map $H_P$ extends to $G$ via the equation $G = PK$.  Let $\alpha^{\vee} \in \mathfrak a_M$ be the coroot corresponding to $\alpha$, and suppose $n' \in \overline{N} \cap N'$.  Is it true that $H_P(n')$ is proportional to $\alpha^{\vee}$?  This is claimed in Waldspurger's writeup on Harish-Chandra's [notes](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1474748003000082) on the proof of the convergence of intertwining operators:

[image]

To compute $H_P(n')$, we need to write $n' = nmk$ for $n \in N, m \in M, k \in K$, so that $H_P(n') = H_P(m)$.  As a start, I could try to show that $\langle \beta, H_P(m)\rangle$ for all $\beta \in \Delta(A_M,N)$ except for $\alpha$.  But I don't see how to use the fact that $n' \in \overline{N} \cap N'$ to tell anything about $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have already know the answer. For those who are interested in it, a proof is given by

Lemme 3.3.1 of *La formule des traces tordue d’après le Friday Morning Seminar* by Labesse and Waldspurger.

In split case, an enlightening proof can be found in

Lemme 8.16.8 of *Le lemme fondamental Pondéré I. Constructions Géométriques* by Chaudouard and Laumon.